# How to tell whether a file system object is a path or a directory

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET How to check if path is a file and not a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory)

Can anyone think of a good way of telling whether a file system object path equates to a a file or a directory?

I did have the following method:

```
public static bool PathIsFile(this string fullPath)
{
    return (Path.GetExtension(fullPath).Length > 0);
}
```

But some files have no extension and some directories have a dot in their name so this is not cutting it.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of knowing just from a string analysis that something is a file or a directory, since, as you noted,

```
C:\WINDOWS\WhoKnowsWhatThisIs
```

might be either a directory or a file.

You'll have to call something like `System.IO.Directory.Exists()` or `System.IO.File.GetAttributes()` to test.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out:

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
```

and

```
System.IO.File.Exists(path);
```

These return boolean, but I can't find out (at the moment) what errors they raise if given a file or directory respectively.

There's also the `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` classes which should help you here.

Answer (score 0):

See [.NET How to check if path is a file and not a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the filesystem.  It always knows.  That is the only fool-proof way.

```
f1 = File(path);
bool isfile = f1.isFile();
bool isdir = f1.isDirectory();
```

Is an example from Java.IO.File.

Comment: you might want to add "java" to 'Interested Tags' so you can quickly see which question is Java-related and which isn't

Answer (score 0):

Check out the isFile method.  It's used here:

http://tools.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Development/C-Programming-Namespaces-and-the-Base-Classes-Part-4-File-and-Folder-Operations/