# Efficient way to decide between file or directory deletion

Tags: c#, file-io, io, directory

My method get array of string as an argument, that represent paths to files and directories that my program have to delete. In foreach loop i have no idea if string represent path to file or directory, so i don't know which method i should use File.Delete() or Directory.Delete.

I create something like this but i think it could be done better :)

```
foreach (string path in deleteItems)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }   
            catch (IOException)
            {
                try { File.Delete(path); }
                catch (IOException e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
            }
        }
```

Somebody have any idea how to do this code better?

Edit: or i think it could be better

```
            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
                continue;
            }
            if(Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.Delete(path);
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: Check this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory-c-net).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see whether or not the string is a file or a directory, simple check to see whether it is one of the two using;

```
foreach (string path in deleteItems)
{
  if(File.Exists(path)){
    File.Delete(path);
  }elseif(Directory.Exists(path)){
    Directory.Delete(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sort of figured that you would come to that conclusion eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395226/284240) you should check the [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx):

```
foreach (string path in deleteItems)
{
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\Temp");
    //detect whether its a directory or file
    if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        Directory.Delete(path, true);
    else
        File.Delete(path);
}
```

(omitted exception handling for better readability)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Directory.Exists(path)
for eg

```
if(Directory.Exists(path))

   Directory.Delete(path);

else

   File.Delete(path);
```