# Check if file or folder by given path exists

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm getting the user to pass a path as a string.

A **path** could be something like

`C:\someFolder`

`C:\someFolder\someFile`

`C:\someFolder\someFile.jpg`

I want to check if the given path is a file or folder, and if it is a file, I want to check if it actually exits.

I've been using `FileAttributes fileRoot = File.GetAttributes(@path);` to check if its a file or a folder but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I think fileAttributes works properly to identify if it a file or directory. can you please tell me why it is not working properly?

Comment: Duplicate of [Better way to check if Path is a File or a Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory)

Comment: The question is duplicate, next time try to search at least in SO !
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory?lq=1

Comment: @mybirthname I checked that question out. It didn't have anything about the file possibly not existing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\";
            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

            switch (attributes)
            {
                case FileAttributes.Directory:
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                        Console.WriteLine("This directory exists.");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("This directory does not exist.");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                        Console.WriteLine("This file exists.");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("This file does not exist.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working sample I wrote for you. It gets the `path` variable, determines whether it's a dir or a file and then checks to see if it exists. Just make sure you handle the `FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);` line appropriately such as placing it in a try/catch block because if the file or folder does not exist it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and complete answer.

Comment: You're very welcome. Just make sure you handle the `FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);` line appropriately such as placing it in a try/catch block because if the file or folder does not exist it will throw an exception.

Comment: Ha, yes I just realized that.

Comment: Sorry haha, I should have included that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Path = @"C:\Abhishek\Documents";
        string filePath = @"C:\Abhishek\Documents.txt";
        bool isDirExists = Directory.Exists(Path);
        bool isFileExists = File.Exists(filePath);

        if (isDirExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory Exists");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exists");
        }
        if (isFileExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exists");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. This requires you to know in advance whether the string is a Directory or a File.

Comment: @jay_t55 this is the right way to do it, the up voted answer doesn't work in every case ! He just need to check only with one string ...

Comment: Yes but there is possibility that there exists directory as well as file with same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the file exists.

You can use [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if folders exist

And then you can use this to check if it is a file or folder

```
private bool CheckIfExists(string path)
{
    // get the file attributes for file or directory
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(path);

    //detect whether its a directory or file
    if((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        return Directory.Exists(path);
    else
        return File.Exists(path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it does not work for folders. It simply says it `does not exist.`

Comment: @john use Directory.Exists for folders

Answer (score 0):

Would you please clarify this statement:

> but it doesn't work properly

What are the cases for "not properly"?

**Regarding question:**

Does your task require to know if its file or directory?

In case no (i.e. you just want to have "true" if file exists), you can use File.Exists and get needed result.
No exceptions thrown in case you're worried.

```
var filePath = @"d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack\Detrack.bak";
var dirPath = @"d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack\";
var dirPathWithoutTrailingSlash = @"d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack";

Console.WriteLine("Path ({0}) exists = {1}", filePath, new FileInfo(filePath).Exists);
Console.WriteLine("Path ({0}) exists = {1}", dirPath, new FileInfo(dirPath).Exists);
Console.WriteLine("Path ({0}) exists = {1}", dirPathWithoutTrailingSlash, new FileInfo(dirPathWithoutTrailingSlash).Exists);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Results are:

```
Path (d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack\Detrack.bak) exists = True
Path (d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack\) exists = False
Path (d:\Storage\Repo\Detrack) exists = False
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that there were two checks for `exists` -`Directory.Exists` and `File.Exists` and therefore I was getting wrong results, which was why I thought it wasn't working correctly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below to check it:

```
// get the file attributes for file or directory
        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\Temp");

        //detect whether its a directory or file
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            // Its a directory
            // Do something here
        }
        else
        {
            // Its a file
            // Do something here
        }
```