# Finding all possible file path permutations

Tags: c#

I am trying to find all possible permutations of a given file path. This is required to create some directories on a remote server, before transferring some files.

This is my code;

```
 public class PathUtils
{
    public bool IsUNC(String path)
    {
        string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
        return root.StartsWith(new String(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 2));
    }

    public void Combinations(HashSet<String> paths, String path)
    {
        if (!Path.HasExtension(path) && !path.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
        {
            path = path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }

        if (IsUNC(path))
        {
            paths.Add(new String(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 2) + (new Uri(path)).Host);
        }

        String previous = path;

        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetDirectoryName(previous)))
        {
            paths.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(previous));
            previous = Path.GetDirectoryName(previous);
        }

        paths.Add(Path.GetPathRoot(path));
    }
}
```

However, when I give it a `path` of `PRTK 7.0.0\KEYLOK 1.6`, the only value that is returned in the HashSet is `PRTK 7.0.0` when there should be two, `PRTK 7.0.0` and `KEYLOK 1.6`. If I provide a path of `PRTK 7.0.0\KEYLOK 16`, I get the expected result, two items in the hashset - `PRTK 7.0.0` and `KEYLOK 16`.

I'm unsure of why this behavior is happening, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pedantic alert: `\\?\UNC\server\share` is also a [valid UNC path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Also, are you using the mathematical definition of permutations? Are you sure you don't mean path components?

Comment: `Path.HasExtension(@"PRTK 7.0.0\KEYLOK 1.6")` returns `true`. You will probably have to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395226/5095502) to disambiguate between a directory with a `.` in it and a file that has an extension.