# Finding if an item in a directory is file or folder using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, directoryinfo

I want to check if each item in a directory is of type file or a folder in using C#. I want to write something like the code below. But `IsInstanceOfType(FileInfo)`and `IsInstanceOfType(DirectoryInfo)` is not allowed in C#.

```
    DirectoryInfo dirPrograms = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);                     
    foreach(var dir in dirPrograms.EnumerateFileSystemInfos())
        {
            if (dir.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(FileInfo))
                  //do something
            elseif (dir.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(DirectoryInfo))
                //do something
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to check if a Path is a File or a Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-a-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) operator to check whether an object can be converted to a specific type:

```
if (dir is FileInfo)
  // do something
else (dir is DirectoryInfo)
  // Do something
```

Comment: Yeah.. I missed that one ! Thanks a lot. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* solve this using the `is` operator, I'd rather avoid using reflection and check it by inspecting the `Attributes` property like this:

```
foreach (var dir in dirPrograms.EnumerateFileSystemInfos())
{
    if (dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    {
        // It's a dir
    }
    else
    {
        // It's a file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have permission to read all the folders.  So you need to recursively go through folders and continue when you get an exception like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);
            
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
             

                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the `FileSystemInfo.FullPath` and then the `Directory` and `File` classes to check if the file or folder exists.

So in your `foreach` loop it would be something like this.

```
if (Directory.Exists(dir.FullPath))
     // do something it its a folder
elseif (File.Exists(dir.FullPath))
     // do something if its a file, shouldn't have to check this condition really but it wouldn't hurt to be safe
```