# Is there a way of knowing if a certain path is a directory path

Tags: .net, f#

I have a string var (path) that represents a path:

```
printfn "Please enter a path"
let path = System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Is there a way of knowing wheter this path is for a directory or a regular file?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory-c-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Directory.Exists(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) and [`File.Exists(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx).

Comment: does File.Exists(path) just check if any kind of file (including a directory) exists in this path, or only regular files?

Comment: I think `File.Exists` works for regular files only.