# Decide if path is file or directory (the path does not exist on disk)

Tags: .net, file, path, directory

I am trying to extract the directory from a path that may or may not contain the file name. The problem is that when I am trying to get the directory name of a path that is already a directory, the Path.GetDirectoryName() returns the upper level of that dir. The path is loaded from the database so I cannot check the file attributes.

**Ex.**
Path.GetDirectoryName("D:\Work\Project\Sources\trunk\Project2\bin\Debug") returns "D:\Work\Project\Sources\trunk\Project2\bin\"

I was thinking of a simple algorithm, that checks if the path contains the "." character; if yes, then we are dealing with a path that contains the file name. Unfortunately the directory names can also contain the "." character.

I know that there is no perfect solution for this issue but what is the next best thing?

*There is already a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory) about the issue but it assumes that the file or directory already exists.*

Comment: There is no correct answer. File names *don't* have to contain a '.', and (as you say) directory names *can* include a '.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your directory or file doesn't exist, there is no way to know if it's a file or a directory.

In your example `D:\Work\Project\Sources\trunk\Project2\bin\Debug`, there could be a file named `Debug` (without extension) in the `bin` directory.

Another example: `D:\Work\Project\Sources\trunk\Project2\bin\Debug\file.exe`, there could be a directory named `file.exe` which is a sub-dir of `Debug`...

Answer (score 1):

for your scenario and if your cases really involve only a "file.ext" format, then the following regex will answer ehat you need

```
^(.*/)([^/]*)$
```