# Drag&Drop - differentiate between file and folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to difference when the user drops a folder or a file but i get a error.

UPDATE

The error is:

```
Conversion from string "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\W" to type 'Long' is not valid.
```

(Notice that the path, is incomplete)

The IDE highlights this error-line:

```
If ((attributes And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory) Then
```

I don't know if the problem is in the conversion or what, but if I use a msgbox before the problematic error-line, I can see how the path is correct:

```
MessageBox.Show(Objetos(0))
If ((attributes And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory) Then
```

[image]

This is the sub:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles foldertextbox.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim Objetos As String() = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)

        Dim attributes = Objetos(0)
        If ((attributes And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory) Then
            MsgBox("it's a dir")
        Else
            MsgBox("it's a file")
        End If

        foldertextbox.Text = Objetos(0)
        userSelectedFolderPath = Objetos(0)
        My.Settings.folderpath = Objetos(0)
        My.Settings.Save()
        playerargs = Nothing
        updatecheckboxes()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What "error"? You get an exception or it doesnt recognize dirs (always as "file")?

Comment: Sorry for that, and thankyou for comment, I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `attributes` variable actually holds the file/dir name/path, if you want to test if its a directory, you can try:

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(attributes)
```

Like this:

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(attributes) Then
    MsgBox("it's a dir")
ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists(attributes) Then
    MsgBox("it's a file")
End If
```

**UPDATE**

Check this answer, has better checking, maybe was what you were looking for:
[.NET How to check if path is a file and not a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439447/net-how-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-and-not-a-directory)

```
Dim isDir As Boolean = (System.IO.File.GetAttributes(path) And 
        System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, with your first comment was enough